# How can I create containers at time of instance creation from my project container images

Tags: docker, gcloud, google-kubernetes-engine, google-container-registry

I am trying to start a `container-vm` Google Compute Engine VM instance with a container created when the machine starts. An example of this you find in this documentation section: [Creating containers at time of instance creation](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/containers/container_vms).

Everything works fine with the given example:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: service
spec:
  containers:
    - name: jillix-service
      image: gcr.io/google-containers/busybox
      command: ['nc', '-p', '8000', '-l', '-l', '-e', 'echo', 'hello world!']
      imagePullPolicy: Always
      ports:
        - containerPort: 8000
          hostPort: 80
```

but when I try to use instead my own container image, the image it is not working:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: service
spec:
  containers:
    - name: jillix-service
      image: gcr.io/sigma-cairn-99810/service
      imagePullPolicy: Always
      ports:
        - containerPort: 8000
          hostPort: 80
```

In the working example docker reports the following container images to be on the VM:

```
$ sudo  docker images
REPOSITORY                         TAG                 IMAGE ID            CREATED             VIRTUAL SIZE
gcr.io/google_containers/pause     0.8.0               2c40b0526b63        7 months ago        241.7 kB
gcr.io/google-containers/busybox   latest              4986bf8c1536        10 months ago       2.433 MB
```

but when I use my container image, this is missing:

```
gabriel@container-image-builder:~$ sudo docker images
```

REPOSITORY                       TAG                 IMAGE ID            CREATED             VIRTUAL SIZE
    gcr.io/google_containers/pause   0.8.0               2c40b0526b63        7 months ago        241.7 kB

So, I assume that this is the reason why my container is not starting. But why doesn't the VM download my `gcr.io/sigma-cairn-99810/service` image?

Does it have to do anything with authentication? (When I manually log into the VM and `gcloud docker pull`, I am prompted to `gcloud auth login` first, then I can pull my image and `docker run` it normally and everything works.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does the container-vm you started have (at least) the storage "read only" scope?

You can check this with:

```
curl -H 'Metadata-Flavor: Google' http://metadata.google.internal./computeMetadata/v1/instance/service-accounts/default/scopes
```

Comment: Should I run this from the VM itself or from the place where I create the VM? Is there an extra dot after `internal.`? From the VM I get a 404 HTML response (with or without the extra dot), From the machine that created the VM it does not recognise the domain in the URL (`metadata.google.internal`) which make me assume I have to run it form inside the machine.

Comment: The trailing dot is weird, and makes it a fully-qualified domain name (FQDN).

Can you try removing `default/scopes` from the end?  It looks like your VM may not have any credentials.  Can you add `--scopes=storage-ro` to the gcloud command to create the instance?

Comment: Yes, my instance had no service accounts. I added the `<project-id>-compute@developer.gserviceaccount.com` service account and gave it the scope `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/devstorage.read_only`. Now the private container image is pulled during the image creation and my container is started with the machine. Thanks!